# Offline extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

How download offline extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell ?

I try like this template

```
https://${ publisher }.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/${ publisher }/extension/${ extension name }/${ version }/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage
```

But this link https://microsoft.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/microsoft/extension/PowerShell/0.6.1/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage return error.

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The requested extension doesn't exist.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.WebApi.ExtensionDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.WebApi","typeKey":"ExtensionDoesNotExistException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell can extract publisher and extension name. On page find last version.

```
publisher = ms-vscode
extension name = PowerShell
version = 0.6.1
```

Working link https://ms-vscode.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-vscode/extension/PowerShell/0.6.1/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage

Rename `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage` to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIX`.

Drag and drop to VSCore. VSCore install offline this extension.